# How to embed matplotlib graph in some area of a tkinter canvas?

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter, canvas

Hello I am trying to embed a matplotlib graph to an especific area of a canvas, and I am having some problems trying to make the toolbar work properly. Here is what I have so far:

```py
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
matplotlib.use("TkAgg")
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2Tk
import tkinter as tk

def on_closing():
    root.quit()
    root.destroy()

root = tk.Tk()
root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", on_closing)

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width = 500, height=400, highlightthickness=0)
canvas.pack()
# create Frame
x0, y0, x1, y1 = (10, 10, 490, 390)
frame = tk.Frame(canvas, width=x1-x0, height=y1-y0)
window = canvas.create_window(x0, y0, anchor="nw",
window=frame, width=x1-x0, height=y1-y0)
# Create matplotlib graph
figure, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],[5,6,1,3,8,9,3,5])
ax.set(xlabel='something', ylabel='something',
       title='something')
ax.grid()

canvas_matplotlib = FigureCanvasTkAgg(figure, frame)
canvas_matplotlib.draw()
canvas_matplotlib.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.BOTTOM, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

toolbar = NavigationToolbar2Tk(canvas_matplotlib, frame)
toolbar.update()
canvas_matplotlib._tkcanvas.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)
root.mainloop()
```

I dont understand why the toolbar wont appear.

EDIT:

What I want is for the plot and the toolbar to occupy exactly the area of the canvas defined.

Comment: Your `canvas` is not expanding, and there is a height limit set in your `canvas.create_window`. Use `canvas.pack(fill="y", expand=True)`, and delete the height on your `create_window`.

Comment: I see, so the size of the plot cant be set depending on the widget parent?, if I want to put the plot the only way to change the size is by matplotlib figsize? Basicaly I would like for the plot to fit perfectly in the canvas area.